# ROP chain. Somehow two bytes are overwritten

Tags: buffer-overflow

I am learning about ROP chains. I am facing a behavior I cannot explain.

This is my sample code:

```
int main(int argc, char* args[]) {  
    char text[200];
    scanf("%s", text);
    return 0;
}
```

I create a ROP chain that starts like this:

```
p = 'A'* 212

p += pack('<I', 0x0806ea3a) # pop edx ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080eb060) # @ .data
p += pack('<I', 0x080bbd06) # pop eax ; ret
```

However when I execute the exploit I get a segmentation fault.

```
Stopped reason: SIGSEGV
0xbf00bd06 in ?? ()
```

To me, it seems that for some reason the first two bytes of the address I used in the ROP chain (`0x080bbd06`) are overwritten (`0xbf00bd06`). I don’t know why this happens. Aany ideas how to fix this?

Comment: What do you have at 0x080eb060?

Comment: gdb-peda$ x/i 0x080eb060
   0x80eb060: add    BYTE PTR [eax],al

gdb-peda$ x/s 0x080eb060
0x80eb060: ""

gdb-peda$ x/x 0x080eb060
0x80eb060: 0x00